# Dependency Injection - Is it ever a good idea to create instances in a class?

Tags: language-agnostic, dependency-injection

Ever since I learned about Dependency Injection I am having hard time to decide whether something should be injected or created inside a class.

Consider the following sample that does not use DI:

```
class Car
{
    private Wheels _wheels;
    private Chasis _chasis;
    private Fuel _fuel;

    public Car()
    {
        _wheels = new Wheels();
        _chasis = new Chasis();
        _fuel = new Fuel();
    }

    public ExhaustGas Exhaust
    {
        get
        {
            return new ExhaustGas();
        }
    }
}
```

What of these instances, that are created inside the Car would you inject? If so how do you decide?

Here is my reasoning:

- **Fuel** - Since fuel is obtained from external sources and I can definitely see reasons for the fuel to change, I'd add abstraction to it (IFuel) and inject it.
- **Wheels** - Even though the wheels are part of the car, you can certainly change the wheels easily. So I say it should be injected as well.
- **Chasis** - This one takes more thought. Chassis is a very essential part of the car so getting it as an external dependency seems a little weird. However, you can certainly run tests on the Chasis alone and the Car could be tested with a dummy (even though I am not sure whether it should). Should such an essential part of the object be injected?
- **ExhaustGas** - This one is even harder. I could inject a factory that creates IExhaustGas on demand but I am not sure whether I should. Should I not inject this instance as factory because it is created on demand? If not, what should be my reasoning in this case?

I'd love to hear your opinion on the variables I presented here and a more generic reasoning on how you decide when to inject something and when not to.

Comment: As far as testing is concerned, the question is "do you want to be able to test that `Car` correctly uses the public interface of `ExhaustGas`, and does not depend on the implementation?". If you want to be able to test that, then you'll want to inject `ExhaustGas` and mock it under test. If you don't care to test that (which means that in effect you are saying that `ExhaustGas` is an internal detail of the units within `Car` that use it) then there's no point injecting it, but are you sure that's as small as your units can be?

Comment: What makes a certain class "an object detail" however? Do you mean cases in which the internal object is a simple data-only object that is used merely for additional data storage and can easily be tested through the main object? Does it mean you'd create instances in your classes and use injected factories for every instance that is created inside?

Comment: it's your decision what's an internal detail and what has a public interface that you code to and test to. The tension is between the cost of testing vs. the value of testing. There are some characteristics that make it more *likely* that the value of testing is low (for example if the interface to the `ExhaustGas` object is so simple that you don't believe it's possible for `Car` to misuse it), but I think it's ultimately a professional judgement call. Most good practice guides would say "if in doubt, test it" or even "always test it just in case".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, *all* external dependencies should be injected. The reason is simple: you want to be able to *mock* dependencies for testing and have the flexibility to substitute them later when necessary.

To deal with the complexity of injecting everything, there are several strategies. If you only want to inject a few things, make it optional:

```
class Foo {

    private _bar
    private _baz

    public Foo(Bar bar = null, Baz baz = null) {
        if (!bar)  bar = new Bar;
        if (!baz)  baz = new Baz;

        _bar = bar
        _baz = baz
    }

}
```

This still has all the advantages of dependency injection while avoiding the necessary instantiation madness.

Alternatively, use factories like `CarDependencyFactory`, which can instantiate all required dependencies in one class. Optionally make that optional too.

Dependency injection containers/managers/frameworks can help as well. The bottom line is though that you should inject *everything*, unless you are really really sure the dependency will never need to be replaced and it is okay to *couple* one piece of code to another.

Also see [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/).

Comment: What defines an object as an external dependency? What kind of object that is instantiated inside your class would be NOT an external dependency?

Comment: It comes down to *code coupling*. If you instantiate `Bar` in `Foo`, then `Foo` is *coupled to* `Bar`. You cannot use `Foo` without `Bar`. This may be okay now, but suppose you later want to add a, say, memcache layer to `Bar`. Suddenly `Bar` depends on memcache, which is quite a dependency. Now `Foo` depends on memcache as well, irrevocably. If you can't inject `Bar` into `Foo`, you can't even test `Foo` independently of `Bar` independently of memcache. *Everything* is a dependency. Some dependencies are trivial, others are not, and some change from trivial to pretty heavy over time.

Comment: If you are 120% sure that a class will never change, even later, even over time, you can instantiate it right in the class. Say, you use the PHP `DateTime` or `PDO` classes. Those are pretty guaranteed to exist and you will hardly want to change them. (In the case of PDO, that makes your class depend on a database. Make sure the primary responsibility of that class is *database access*, don't put a lot of functionality in there which you will then be unable to use without a database.) Anything else is always an unknown and may or may not get you into hot water later.

Comment: Trivial example from personal experience: There was a class which did phone number format validation. That's a pretty trivial thing, right? So it was called directly from all over the place. Well, turns out there's a great phone number validation library by Google, but there are only Java and Python implementations. So that class was changed to make a call to a Python script. That was not so bad in production (heavily cached etc.), but all tests now ran 1000% slower, causing the test suite to run for minutes instead of seconds. All because the class couldn't be mocked.

Comment: Also bear in mind that it might be possible to change the dependency *later* from fixed to injectable. You can often do it without changing the existing calling code, if you add the newly-injected object as a parameter with a default value. That could leave your class dependent on the default *existing* but not on it *working*, which is a lesser fixed dependency but still not ideal. You have to be able to identify what interfaces can never be changed in future, and put extra care/caution into their design using time you've saved on interfaces that can change.

Comment: So for example, suppose you have a `DatabaseConnection` class that's used directly by your `Model` class. Some time later you realise this is a terrible mistake, and you want to test the `Model` class using a mocked connection. If you do what I say above then you're left with a `Model` that uses a `DatabaseConnection` as a default. Under test you supply the mock, so the actual database doesn't need to be reachable because the `Model` won't use it.

Comment: @Steve So basically the optional injection I cite in my answer? Yes, you may be able to change this later, but for that all object construction needs to happen in the constructor. So you need to at least plan for *that* from the beginning.

Comment: @deceze: yes, my point relates to your comments, you can change "no injection" to "optional injection" without having to change code that calls the things that have the dependency. So in your example where the tests slowed down, you'd find the most frequent call locations to the phone number doohicky, switch them from no injection to optional injection, and under test pass them the performance-improving mock. In extremis you'd use global configuration to make the phone number doohicky itself rely on an interchangeable component to do the validation, but global configuration is icky.

Comment: @Steve Sure, but that *does* mean you need to change code around, potentially a lot, depending on how deeply ingrained and how widely used that dependency is. By (optionally) injecting from the beginning you want to minimize exactly that. Anyway, agreed. :)

Comment: @deceze: yes, I'm sort of assuming in your example that 85% of the cost comes from 15% of the call sites, or some equally-made-up statistic that's supposed to represent typical code bases ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the informative discussion!